# Styling R shiny titlePanel tags$a text

Tags: r, shiny, tags

I'm trying to include an additional header line in my `R` `Shiny` `titlePanel`, which is a hyperlink and hence I'm using the `tags$a` funcrion, and would like it to have a smaller font size than the first header line.

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  titlePanel(tags$a("Shiny Tutorial",href="https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html")),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see:
[image]

The first header line: `"Hello Shiny!"` and second: `"Shiny Tutorial"` have the same font size, but I'd like to have the second header title in a smaller font size.

In addition, any idea how would I be able to have these two headers in the same line?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're accidentally creating duplicate titlePanels, which I don't like.

However, keeping that going, this works for me and you can adjust the size where `h1` is the biggest and `h6` is the smallest, per typical HTML.

What if you tried something like...

```
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!", windowTitle = "Hello Shiny!"),
  titlePanel(tags$h4(
    tags$a("Shiny Tutorial",href="https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html")
    )
    ),
```

note that without the argument `windowTitle = ...` your window title in your browser will become the HTML text in the `tags$a(...)` function.

Comment: This is great @Andrew McCartney - thanks a lot. Is it possible to have them in the same line (keeping the different font sizes)?

Answer (score 3):

The `titlePanel` function generates a single second heading element (`<h2>`), which is a bit misleading as it seems that it would generate a header container. The intended use of heading levels (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, and `h6`) is for document structure and hierarchy rather than font sizing. All webpages should have one `h1` element that describes the entire page.

To follow good semantic HTML practices, use the appropriate heading element (`h1`; or other heading depending on your document structure) and styling using CSS. Page headings should ideally be wrapped in the `<header>` element. I added to your example and applied the CSS styles to render the heading and link inline (via flex). I also added the CSS class `col-sm-12` to "hook" into bootstrap.

```r
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x <- faithful$waiting
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        hist(x,
            breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
            xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
            main = "Histogram of waiting times"
        )
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            HTML(
                ".title-panel {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: flex-start;
                    align-items: flex-end;
                    padding: 16px;
                }",
                ".title-panel h1 {
                    font-size: 24pt;
                    margin: 0;
                    margin-right: 12px;
                    line-height: 1.2;
                }",
                ".title-panel a {
                    font-size: 16pt;
                    margin: 0;
                }"
            )
        )
    ),
    title = "Hello Shiny",
    tags$header(
        class = "col-sm-12 title-panel",
        tags$h1("Hello Shiny"),
        tags$a(
            href = "https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html",
            "Shiny Tutorial"
        )
    ),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput(
                inputId = "bins",
                label = "Number of bins:",
                min = 1,
                max = 50,
                value = 30
            )
        ),

        mainPanel(
            plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
        )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```